# Qt C++ access property

Tags: c++, qt

I have two widgets:

```
class Widget: public QWidget
{
   public:
   Button* button;
   Widget();
   int value; // need to get this var
}

Widget::Widget()
{
   button = new Button(this);
}


class Button: public QPushButton
{
   public:
   Button(QWidget* parent = 0);
}

Button::Button(QWidget* parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
   this->parentWidget()->value // dont see var
}
```

How can i see property from parent widget? What the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: what exacly do you mean with see? in your editor (intellisense) - on screen?

Comment: sorry for the inaccuracy. I meant to be accessible to the variable

Answer (score 1):

Your Button constructor could take a Widget instead of a QWidget:

```
class Button: public QPushButton
{
public:
   Button(Widget* parent = 0);
}

Button::Button(Widget* parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
   parent->value = 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work: 'class QWidget' has no member named 'value'.

Comment: @Ramix: Did you notice that the parameter is of type `Widget*`, not `QWidget*`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices

Change

```
Button::Button(QWidget * parent )
{
}
```

**TO**

```
Button::Button(Widget * parent )
{
   //Here class type is already known
   parent->value;
}
```

Or

use **static_cast<Widget*>(parent)** within the constructor to cast **parent** to your class if you know for sure it is always going to be the case. Otherwise use **dynamic_cast<Widget*>(parent)**

```
Button::Button(QWidget * parent )
{ 
    Widget* wparent = static_cast<Widget*>(parent);
    //now your can access wparent member variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the `Q_OBJECT` macro. Then you can use the [property system](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/properties.html). It is not intended to access the members of a QWidget directly. They can't even linked that way - of course you *could* force your Button using (only) your `Widget` class but that would lead to tight coupling.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only needed in the constructor, why not just pass it as a parameter?

```
class Button: public QPushButton
{
public:
    Button(int value, QWidget* parent = 0);
}
```

If it's needed somewhere other than the constructor, it would be very helpful to know what this value is doing. Is it changing the appearance? Is it changing behavior? I ask because most ways of allowing you to directly access the parent tie your widget to its parent, and to me it seems like there are better ways to design it.

For example, if `value` changes in some important way in the parent, call a method in your button class to notify them of the change. That way anybody can use your button class as long as they call the proper methods.

```
class Button: public QPushButton
{
public:
    Button(int value, QWidget* parent = 0);

    void updateValue(int value);
private:
    int value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just a type conversion will do the trick:

```
Button::Button(QWidget* parent)
{
    cout<<((Widget*)(this->parentWidget())->value; //print parent's value
}
```

However, the logic of your code is strange: when you create an instance of Widget, the constructor of Button will be invoked first, in which Widget's value is retrieved. However, the Widget class is not constructed yet, so value is uninitialized.